# Why did ubuntu restart?

Tags: 18.04, reboot

I've been struggling to find why my ubuntu system is rebooting on its own.

I started looking for answers in /var/log/syslog and could not understand - what is causing the reboot. Something happened just before 11:17AM, following that system has been rebooted. Can someone help me?
[Another answer that helped me got get to this log.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/how-to-find-out-from-the-logs-what-caused-system-shutdown)
Here is the syslog file:

```
Dec 12 08:25:09 MKMH01 rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.32.0" x-pid="716" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Dec 12 08:25:11 MKMH01 anacron[722]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Dec 12 08:25:11 MKMH01 anacron[722]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Dec 12 08:35:01 MKMH01 CRON[3999]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 08:35:09 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Dec 12 08:35:09 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Dec 12 08:45:01 MKMH01 CRON[4293]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 08:55:01 MKMH01 CRON[4567]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 08:56:07 MKMH01 kernel: [ 2161.871675] usb 6-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Dec 12 08:56:07 MKMH01 kernel: [ 2161.897810] usb 6-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0817
Dec 12 08:56:07 MKMH01 kernel: [ 2161.897812] usb 6-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Dec 12 08:56:07 MKMH01 kernel: [ 2161.897813] usb 6-1: Product: USB3.0 Hub             
Dec 12 08:56:07 MKMH01 kernel: [ 2161.897814] usb 6-1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
Dec 12 08:56:07 MKMH01 kernel: [ 2161.898777] hub 6-1:1.0: USB hub found
Dec 12 08:56:07 MKMH01 kernel: [ 2161.899001] hub 6-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
Dec 12 08:56:07 MKMH01 upowerd[1010]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0
Dec 12 08:56:07 MKMH01 upowerd[1010]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-1
Dec 12 09:05:01 MKMH01 CRON[4897]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 09:05:09 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Dec 12 09:05:09 MKMH01 anacron[4903]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2019-12-12
Dec 12 09:05:09 MKMH01 anacron[4903]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Dec 12 09:15:01 MKMH01 CRON[5235]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 09:17:01 MKMH01 CRON[5295]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 12 09:25:01 MKMH01 CRON[5529]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 09:35:01 MKMH01 CRON[5817]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 09:45:01 MKMH01 CRON[6102]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 09:55:01 MKMH01 CRON[6420]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 10:04:08 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Dec 12 10:04:08 MKMH01 anacron[6678]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2019-12-12
Dec 12 10:04:08 MKMH01 anacron[6678]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Dec 12 10:05:01 MKMH01 CRON[6701]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 10:15:01 MKMH01 CRON[7004]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 10:17:01 MKMH01 CRON[7049]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 12 10:25:01 MKMH01 CRON[7284]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 10:35:01 MKMH01 CRON[7575]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 10:45:01 MKMH01 CRON[7865]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 10:55:01 MKMH01 CRON[8159]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 11:04:22 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Dec 12 11:04:22 MKMH01 anacron[8421]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2019-12-12
Dec 12 11:04:22 MKMH01 anacron[8421]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Dec 12 11:05:01 MKMH01 CRON[8444]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 11:15:01 MKMH01 CRON[8730]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-modules-load[323]: Inserted module 'lp'
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-modules-load[323]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-modules-load[323]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started Set the console keyboard layout.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-networkd[347]: Enumeration completed
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-networkd[347]: lo: Link is not managed by us
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core, revision 8039...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core, revision 8213...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for code, revision 21...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for core, revision 8039.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for core, revision 8213.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-networkd-wait-online[379]: ignoring: lo
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-networkd-wait-online[379]: message repeated 4 times: [ ignoring: lo]
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-udevd[359]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-networkd-wait-online[379]: ignoring: lo
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-networkd-wait-online[379]: ignoring: lo
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for code, revision 21.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-udevd[354]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Reached target Sound Card.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-5"
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Found device INTEL SSDPEKNW512G8 EFI\x20System\x20Partition.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/276D-AB39...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-fsck[631]: fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-fsck[631]: 0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-fsck[631]:  Automatically removing dirty bit.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-fsck[631]: Performing changes.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd-fsck[631]: /dev/nvme0n1p1: 12 files, 1558/130812 clusters
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/276D-AB39.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Mounting /boot/efi...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Mounted /boot/efi.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Starting Set console font and keymap...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Starting AppArmor initialization...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started Set console font and keymap.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 apparmor[640]:  * Starting AppArmor profiles
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 apparmor[640]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Dec 12 11:17:42 MKMH01 apparmor[640]:    ...done.
```

Comment: Is this Debian or Ubuntu? What is this cron job? `Dec 12 11:15:01 MKMH01 CRON[8730]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)`

Comment: It is Ubuntu 18.04 budgie dwm

Comment: have you checked the heat/temp of the cpu? I recently had a similar problem and it wasn't until I started manually generating a lot of cpu load that I noticed this kernel msg being dumped to the tty `[TEMP] 2019-12-04T14:25:27-05:00 +79.2`.

Comment: How can enable CPU temperature logs?

Comment: When got a socket wired to UPS for the new computer, the electrician set the ups to economy mode, which was causing this issue, after switching back to ups mode in the inverter issue is resolved. If anyone facing this issue, look around the inverter, one may find the switch to turn on the UPS.